# Monitor Intel package states with intel_pstate driver

Tags: kernel, power-management, intel, powertop

Is there a way to monitor Intel package states with intel_pstate driver?

I'm running kernel 4.8.0-1-amd64 with intel_pstate driver on i7-6700k.

powertop reports following error:

> modprobe cpufreq_stats failed

It sounds normal because of intel_pstate driver use instead of ACPI one.

powertop displays 0% for all package states :

[image: powertop idle stats]

additionally frequencies are not listed :
[image: powertop frequency stats]

i7z seems to display only core states :
[image: i7z]

Thanks

Comment: Only cores states are shown, because that is all there is to show. The 2 CPUs on one core will always be in the same C state. You can also use turbostat in debug mode to show core states.

Comment: Addendum: there can be differences between C0 and C1 times between CPUs on the same core. Turbostat shows the information.

Comment: From my understanding, left section called "Package" in "Idle stats" tab in powertop should display package states. There are listed as pc2 to pc10 in first screenshot. But in my case those statistics stays at 0%. That's why I looking for another way to monitor package states.

Comment: turbostat shows package C states. I recommend you try it. For a skylake processor you might need a more recent version than the Ubuntu default, not sure. I only ever compile it myself.